# How to get the Woocommerce Current email id (like admin_new_order, customer_processing_order) inside the email template file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email

I am working on customizing the woocommerce email templates according to my own needs. I just wanted to know if I can access the current email id (like customer_processing_order, or admin_new_order) so that I can use it in conditional statements like

```
$email_id = /* Some function to get the email id */

if($email_id == 'admin_new_order') {
//do somthing

}
```

I want to use it inside email-order-details.php and also inside email-order-items.php

Thanks

Comment: echo '<pre>'; print_r($email->id); echo '</pre>';   or  you can print_r the $order and $email in email-order-details.php file .............

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Techno Deviser's comment is correct.

Inside `email-order-details.php` you have a few params available:

```
$order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email
```

`$email` is an object that consists of order info and much more.
I see that `id` is always available.

So you can do:

```
$email_id = $email->id;

if($email_id == 'customer_note') {
  // another id i've seen during testing (just now) is: customer_on_hold_order

  //do somthing
}
```

NOTE: inside `email-order-items.php` the `$email` param is not available. For now i'm not really sure how to get some kind of email id in this template, i'll have to investigate more.

Regards, Bjorn

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying that inside the main template, that's why it was not working. Thanks once again.

Comment: is there a way to get this inside this file /templates/emails/email-order-items.php

Comment: With a workaround you can first get the ID by using the hook `woocommerce_email_order_details` then process this with a custom or the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_start` hook.